# CC2540 HIDAdvRemoteControl pairing and bonding

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to flash this configuration (HIDAdvRemoteDongle) to my CC2540 USB dongle.
What we are trying to achieve here is

1) Configure CC2540 with the example (HIDAdvRemoteDongle)

2) Do some changes in HIDAdvRemotedongle so that it pairs with an iPhone or Android which is compatible with BLE.

3) Develop and Android/iPhone App which can send the HID key event to CC2540 dongle.

Note: CC2540 is connected to a target (linux OS machine) where the HID event shall be taken up to a HMI event change in the machine.

I am only successful till Step 1.

Step 2 I need your help?

Step 3 I have the understanding of the Core Bluetooth framework of iOS but not sure if this is achievable in Android, so please confirm that as well?

Awaiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own.
Just trying to explain here so that it shall be useful for others who is in the same page.

HIDAdvRemoteDongle is only for the HID configuration and does it for three things
1) Keyboard
2) Consumer keyboard
3) Mouse

SimpleBLEPeripheral is for the BLE connection (Pairing and bonding) and 5 characteristics (Read,Read/Write & Notify)

If you can integrated both HIDAdvRemoteDongle and SimpleBLEPeripheral projects in the CC2540 Ble project you will have a complete solution
And sending the reports to the host to which dongle is connected is the next episode, which some code needs to be hacked on your own.
Do let me know if anybody need some hands on it, I can help